# Distribution of a Normal, conditioned on the average of a larger sample

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation, gibbs-measure

Consider $Y_1,..., Y_n$ i.i.d. standard normal. Now for some $m>0$ I want to know about

$P(Y_1 \leq t \mid \overline{Y_n} \geq m)$

where $\overline{Y_n}$ is the empirical mean. Intuitivly this should be (or at least converge to as $n \to \infty$) $P(Z \leq t)$ with $Z$ a normal with mean $m$ and variance $1$.

Is this correct and if so, how to prove it?

Comment: You get better spacing if you use `\mid` instead of `|`. The command for $\infty$ is `\infty`.

Comment: It doesn't seem right that $Z$ should have mean $m$ when the empirical mean is known to be *greater than* $m$.

Comment: The case $P(Y_1 \leq \mid \overline{Y_n} = m)$ can be solved by looking at $(Y_1,  \overline{Y_n})$ as a multivariate Gaussian. Then $Y_1 \mid  \overline{Y_n} \overset{d}{=} \mathcal{N}(m, 1-\frac{1}{n})$. 
Indeed by a lengthy calculation with pdfs one obtains $P(Y_1 \leq \mid \overline{Y_n} = m) \to P(Z \leq t)$, however it is untrue for finite $n$.